# Pass string by reference recursively in C

Tags: c, string, recursion, pass-by-reference

The desired output is:

```
orange 1
apple 2
apple 3
```

Instead, I get this:

```
orange 1
apple 2
orange 3
```

when I executed my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void change(char *word) {        // passing pointer to subroutine
    if (word != "apple") {       // WARNING FROM COMPILER
        printf("%s 1\n", word);  // value state #1
        word = "apple";          // change "orange" to "apple"
        change(word);            // recursion happens here
    } else
        printf("%s 2\n", word);  // value state #2
}

int main() {
    char word[] = "orange";

    change(word);                // pass string by reference
    printf("%s 3\n", word);      // value state #3 

    return 0;
}
```

the `gcc compiler` I'm using gives me the following warning:

> *comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]*
>   at line 5:

```
if (word != "apple") {         // WARNING FROM COMPILER
```

I have tried so many ways but still failed to make a proper pass-by-reference from `main()` to `change()` as indicated in #3 state print. It should work recursively too.

Could you spot any problems with my code?

Comment: [`man 3 strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: @chrk I afraid `man 3` it wouldn't be enough. Judging from the code, a lot more reading of K&R may be in order.

Comment: Technically C doesn't *have* pass by reference, it only have pass by value. It can be *emulated* using pointers.

Comment: when the compiler gives a warning, fix the underlying problem, in this case probably by: ` if ( strcmp( word, "apple") ) {`  Of course, to use `strcmp()` need to have `#include <string.h>` at the top of the code

Comment: this line, in the `change()` function: `word = "apple"; ` is not what is wanted.  it just fiddles with some pointers.  suggest: `strcpy( word, "apple" );   Note: this is rather risky, (although it will work in this case) because if the new value were longer than the `word[]` array, then this would overflow the `word[] array, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Please respect the warning. Don't do comparison of String literals.

But, coming to the point of why you are not getting your expected result, the reason is that though you are passing a pointer, you are passing it by value. So, even though you think you are assigning a new address to the variable word, the same doesn't reflect back in your caller function.

Solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void change(char *word) {         
    if (strcmp(word, "apple")) {        
        printf("%s 1\n", word);  
        strcpy(word, "apple");          
        change(word);            
    } else
        printf("%s 2\n", word);  // value state #2
}

int main() {
    char word[20]; 

    strcpy(word, "orange");
    change(word);                // pass string by reference
    printf("%s 3\n", word);      // value state #3 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Works like a charm. BTW, I just edit your code to include `<string.h>` library.

Answer (score 5):

You can't compare string using the equality or inequality operators, it will compare the *pointers* `word` and the one the array `"apple"` decays to.

Also, you can't use the assignment operator in the code, as that will assign to the local pointer variable `word` inside the function only.

To solve the first problem, use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) instead, and for the second use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). But be careful when using `strcpy` so you don't copy a to long string that writes beyond the end of the original array.

Comment: Okay, so `strcmp` solved warning issue.

The main point is an ability to make string pointers works recursively.
Maybe you can show me example from anywhere that demonstrates this concept.

Answer (score 1):

The `!=` reference does not work. You need to use `strcmp()` for comparison.

Similarly, changing the contents of the buffer requires `strcpy()`.

Additionally, the size of the buffer would not be correct as "apple" creates a buffer of 6 characters (to include the ending '\0' NULL character). "orange" requires a buffer of size 7, so you will have a buffer overflow problem as well if the initial word is smaller than orange (though your example code does set it to orange).

You should make your buffer big enough to fit the largest size needed for your words and call `strlen()` to check the size of the new word against the known maximum buffer size assuming that you want a more general case and not just "apple" and "orange" in your change function.

Once you fix these problems properly, you should see better results.

Comment: The word orange is created first, so there wont be an overflow but you should mention that a check needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void change(char *word){         //passing pointer to subroutine
    if(!strcmp(word,"apple")){         //returns 0 when strings are equal
        printf("%s 1\n", word);  //value state #1
        strcpy(word,"apple");          //change "orange" to "apple"
        change(word);            //recursion happens here
    }
    else printf("%s 2\n", word); //value state #2
}

int main(){
    char word[] = "orange";

    change(word);                //pass string by reference
    printf("%s 3\n", word);      //value state #3 

    return 0;
}
```

[strcmp() description here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm)

Comment: can anyone tell me please what's problem with this change?

Comment: ya its working, I have used it before also tried it now on tutorials point.

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34619101/1294207) answer, you are assigning a char * to a string literal that will disappear when it exits the function scope. You need to use `strcpy` ...

Comment: oky then, but why is it so? as we are sending address of first value in function